# Android use id from another layout in MainActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, layout, fragment

I created an Android Application which uses Navigation Drawer Activity (Android Studio Build in). Now I add an ListView to one fragment named `fragment_home.xml`. here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/songList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#2196F3"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my `HomeFragment.java` file

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
 
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

}
```

now I want to use the ListView from fragment_home layout to my `MainActivity class`. So how can I do this.
**Please Help Me**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a recyclerView instead of list view :

You can check this official documentation for more details :

[Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)